# Flatten JSON structure with jq without duplicates

Tags: json, jq

I’m starting from this structure:

```json
[{
    "experiment": "ex1",
    "models": [{
        "name": "model1",
        "reference": 0.1,
        "code": [{
            "name": "foo",
            "version": "a",
            "value": 0.2
        },{
            "name": "foo",
            "version": "b",
            "value": 0.2
        },{
            "name": "bar",
            "version": "a",
            "value": 0.15
        }]
    },{
        "name": "model2",
        "reference": 0.12,
        "code": [{
            "name": "foo",
            "version": "a",
            "value": 0.09
        },{
            "name": "baz",
            "version": "a",
            "value": 0.15
        }]
    }]
}]
```

and I want this as the result:

```json
{
  "model": "model1",
  "code": "foo",
  "version": "a"
}
{
  "model": "model1",
  "code": "foo",
  "version": "b"
}
{
  "model": "model1",
  "code": "bar",
  "version": "a"
}
{
  "model": "model2",
  "code": "foo",
  "version": "a"
}
{
  "model": "model2",
  "code": "baz",
  "version": "a"
}
```

So I wrote the following query.

```
.[] | { "model": .name, "code": .code[].name, "version": .code[].version }
```

The problem is that for each use of `.code[]` in the output structure the results are multiplied, resulting in many duplicates. How can I avoid that, and get only the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many similar questions have been asked before<sup>[[1]](/q/63572261)[[2]](/q/62519154)[[3]](/q/62198965)[[4]](/q/56065822)...</sup>. You need to avoid expanding the same array more than once as shown below to prevent a combinatorial explosion.

```
.[].models[] | {model: .name} + (.code[] | {name, version})
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/vL89Iq6Dhe)</sup>